# Installed a ceiling fan with light but switch doesn't turn it on or off

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I just installed a ceiling fan with light and it’s working.

The problem is that the existing wall switch doesn’t turn it on or off.

Is that normal?

The wall switch that powers the light that was there doesn’t energize or de-energize the fan.

Comment: you have another switch that turns it on/off, on what is called 3 way circuit. If so your wiring is incorrect

Comment: Can you provide pictures of before and after of the ceiling box and wall switch?

Comment: does the fan work with the pull chains only or not at all?  If not at all, the fan is off by the pull chain switch.

Comment: Yes, can you provide photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: This sounds like you bypassed a switch loop. Photos of the wiring would make helping you _tremendously_ easier.